# PHP Get String Text From Bytes

Tags: php, text, byte, data-conversion

I was wondering how one would get the Text representation of a series of bytes in PHP? (Basically, the PHP version of C#'s `Encoding.getString(string s)` method.)

I've been scouring google, and I can find how to get a textstring-to-bytes, but not the other way around.

Comment: PHP strings are simple collections of sequential bytes, with no knowledge whatsoever of character encoding or charsets.  Have you tried `echo`?  You may need to provide more information on what your actual goals are.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: My goals were for some sort of validation script. Basically, I'd have a desktop application which would be the login form for a program, and it'd get the bytes of the entered text (in int-like form), then pass it to the PHP script through the URL ($_REQUEST). The PHP script would then decode the int-form bytes back into their string value. This was primarily to hide the credentials for security purposes. If this is not possible, or is a notoriously bad "encryption" method, could you please suggest a better method? Thanks.

Comment: Don't roll your own encryption, hashing, obfscuation, etc.  Your use case calls for SSL.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP such a method:

```
Encoding.GetString Method (Byte[])
```

is not necessary because in PHP, strings are like Byte[]. And that's it. So there is no such method, however you can easily write it yourself:

```
function Encoding_GetString($stringOfBytes) {
    return (string) $byteString;
}
```

If you want to convert an array of integers in the range of 0-255 into a string, you can use [`chr`](http://php.net/chr), [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
$string = implode(array_map('chr', $arrayOfByteIntegers));
```